# Is it possible to get session_id of active driver opened with Selenium and Appium if several drivers were activated?

Tags: selenium, appium

While automating I open several browsers, say Firefox, with

```
driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver3 = webdriver.Firefox()
.....
```

Is there a way to get the `session_id` and webdriver itself of the active Browser?
The same question for Appium. Is it possible to get `session_id` and driver itself of the active device (virtual or real)?

Comment: AFAIK. Selenium have not any control over System Components. All windows for selenium are active where one driver looks at one tab at same time. I assume you need some KeySend into window as this  action requires an active system window. JS have some awareness of windows state so you could inject some code via Selenium that would say set cookies "ACTIVE WINDOW". And you could pull the cookies in different thread. Alternatives will be some Robot or other tool that track windows or many separate displays.

Comment: I don't remember the reason I needed to get active Browser (it was 2 years ago). Just now I checked that there is now problem to make any operation with any (active or not) browser. Say, we have the following piece of code after presented above:

driver1.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q');
search_box.send_keys('geckodriver');
driver2.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q');
search_box.send_keys('geckodriver');

And this code will succeed!

Answer (score 8):

To get the driver session id with Selenium / Java:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

SessionId session = ((FirefoxDriver)driver).getSessionId();
System.out.println("Session id: " + session.toString());
```

To get the remote driver session id with Selenium / Java:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4722/wd/hub"), capabilities);

SessionId session = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getSessionId();
System.out.println("Session id: " + session.toString());
```

Comment: It is not what I am really want. It just returns the session_id of defined driver. Imagine you have several opened browsers. I want to get the id and the driver itself of current (active) driver.

Comment: If you launch 3 browsers, then you'll end up with 3 active browsers. There is no such current active browser. If you are referring to the foreground window, then it should be the last browser launched, driver3 in your case.

Comment: Yes, it is clear that _foreground window_ is the last browser launched, driver3. But imagine you want to write a class that works with _foreground window_. First, the foreground window should be defined with some method of the class and I am looking for the way to get it.

Comment: With Selenium, the browser doesn't need to be focused (set as the foregound window) to be automated.

Answer (score 1):

```
((ChromeDriver)driver).sessionId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DriverFactory. The following snippet (written in Katalon Studio, but using selenium, so I guess it would be similar or same in other tools)

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory as DriverFactory
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as WebDriver

WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver()
WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver()

DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver1)
driver1.get("https://www.example.com")
println DriverFactory.webDriver

DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver2)
driver2.get("https://news.example.com")
println DriverFactory.webDriver
```

will print out to console:

```
ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (fc70e83ced12b3e9beed990e88670d8e)
ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (a810d0cf94dbaf1cbd018542f9c983c3)
```

with session ID in brackets.

Comment: Correct. I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: This [related official post](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/handle-webdrivers.html#use-the-webdriver-object) from Katalon maybe helpful for whom interested in your solution like me. Great thanks.

Comment: My Katalon 7.5.5 not printing sessionid when `println DriverFactory.webDriver`

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: @Male Mrse I added the import rows to help us easy try your code. Please correct them if they are not your implied import.

Comment: From the console log after run in Katalon "2020-08-19 20:32:55.267 INFO  c.k.k.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory    - sessionId = bbd3034445e8bb8dc33778e99d81acf7"

Comment: println DriverFactory.webDriver will give this "com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.SmartWaitWebDriver@1c12f3ee"

Comment: you can see my sample code at [this snapshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqw75573b4x2r2q/2020-08-19%2020_36_06.katalon-println%20DriverFactory.webDriver.png?dl=0)

Comment: I also put full trial code [here on gist.github](https://gist.github.com/namgivu/18bd9ee46a5a7a52713e7e47a660e50d)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for the problem. You could create a Session. This gives you the Webdriver Instance, but also the sessionID.

```
DefaultDriverFactory defaultDriverFactory = new DefaultDriverFactory(Platform.WINDOWS); 
TemporaryFilesystem temporaryFilesystem = TemporaryFilesystem.getDefaultTmpFS(); 
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
Session session = DefaultSession.createSession(defaultDriverFactory, temporaryFilesystem, chromeOptions); 
WebDriver webDriver = session.getDriver();
SessionId sessionId = session.getSessionId();
```