# opening the Firefox browser using WebDriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am very much new to Selenium and WebDriver.

I have few points to clear regarding the way Firefox browser is launched using WebDriver, and please correct me wherever I am wrong.

The following line of code launches Firefox browser with a new session id every time the Firefox web-browser is opened.

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

My questions are:

- Is there any reason (security/performance issue) that WebDriver always opens a fresh Firefox (like a newly installed Firefox with No add-ons/no customization) every time above code is executed?
- does it mean that every time a new and a temporary Firefox profile is created?
- Is Firefox session id the same thing as a Firefox profile, or it means the browsing session which is active until the Firefox is closed?

Please explain me. I am very puzzled.

Comment: I think the details are dependent on the Selenium/WebDriver version you are using. From my experience (with Seleinum 1 and 2) it is like this: Every time a session is launched a new copy of your Firefox profile (default profile, if not specified) is created in your system's temp directory. The reason is probably that - if Selenium crashes - it does not harm your profile that you might use for manual browsing. What do you mean by _Firefox session id_? Where does it appear?

Comment: I got _session id_ from here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36476111/7529915). Is this _Firefox session id_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for Selenium 2.xx and Firefox 45.6esr (on Linux) it is like this:

Every time a session is launched a **new copy** of your Firefox profile  is created in your system's temp directory. If not specified - for example in constructor of `FirefoxDriver(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile)` - the default profile is taken. **In any case, the profile is copied**.

The reason is probably that - if Selenium crashes - it does not harm the profile that you might use for manual browsing. Moreover, the temporary profile is deleted, when calling `WebDriver.quit()`.

So, each session has a unique id and a unique temporary profile. Note that the name of the temporary profile is not derived from the session id.

I suppose it is the same for other Selenium and Firefox versions and even operating systems (at least Windows). To find out, use this code snippet:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.out.println(driver.getSessionId());

String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
System.out.println(tmpDir);

File dir = new File(tmpDir);
String[] files = dir.list();
for (String file : files) {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

The output is something like (first one is session id, last one is name of directory with temporary firefox profile:

```
60bdbf4a-f4b3-4e71-a6be-9e3ad28a3b09
[...]
/tmp
[...]
anonymous8971467451928507515webdriver-profile
```